# What is the difference between the Zohar Hakadosh, the Tikounei Zohar and the Zohar Hadash?

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

What is the difference between these 3 series of sefarim: the Zohar Hakadosh, the Tikounei Zohar and the Zohar Hadash? Also, what is the Matok Midevash in the Zohar?

Answer (score 5):

The Holy Zohar is formatted as a commentary on the 5 books of Moses.

The Tikunim is formatted a series of commentaries on the first word in the Torah (Bereshis).

The Zohar Hadash is additional teachings, and formatted as a commentary on the 5 books of Moses, as well as on the megillos etc.

Mtuk Mdvash is a recent commentary of the Zohar by Rav Daniel Frisch ZTz'l; extremely popular nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! And what is the Matok Midevash?

Comment: updated.........

Comment: What's new in Zohar Chadash?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I think the name refers to the widespread release of the manuscripts, which were printed to the community around 30 years after the release of the first part, "The Zohar"

Comment: Are they all considered to be of the same level of authenticity and age?

Comment: @far22 If you ever come back and see this, don't forget that you can accept this if it helps you.

Comment: Broadly, what are some of the main teachings and concepts covered in the Zohar Chadash and Mtuk Mdvash that are not covered in the Zohar? Those two mostly aren't available in english so I am wondering what crucial teachings someone would miss from just reading the Zohar (HaKadosh)?